# Swashbuckle UI displays same information for different versions

Tags: swagger, swagger-ui, swagger-2.0, swashbuckle

We've implemented Swashbuckle on our Web Api project and i'm noticing that the SwaggerUI test harness displays the exact same information for any version specified in the address. More specifically it displays the swagger information for which ever VersionInfoBuilder comes first within the SwaggerConfig.

So for example if i navigate to "/preview/swagger/index" - the UI displayed is all v1 information not related to version 'preview'.

What am I doing wrong here?

```
public class SwaggerConfig
{
    private SwaggerConfig() { }

    public static void Register()
    {
        var thisAssembly = typeof(SwaggerConfig).Assembly;
        GlobalConfiguration.Configuration
            .EnableSwagger("{apiVersion}/swagger", c =>
            {
                c.MultipleApiVersions(
                    (apiDesc, version) =>
                    {
                        var path = apiDesc.RelativePath.Split('/');
                        var pathVersion = path[0];

                        return CultureInfo.InvariantCulture.CompareInfo.IndexOf(pathVersion, version, CompareOptions.IgnoreCase) >= 0;
                    },
                    vc =>
                    {
                        vc.Version("v1", "Api - v1");
                        vc.Version("preview", "Api - Preview");
                    });
            })
            .EnableSwaggerUi("{apiVersion}/swagger/{*assetPath}", c =>
            {
                c.DisableValidator();
            });
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think the configuration is wrong, it is just that your expectations are not correct.

You do not have to navigate to another Swagger UI (at `preview/docs/index`) but you have to point Swagger UI at another specification. Just enter http://yourserver:yourport/preview/swagger in the input box in the header and press Explore. Swagger UI will now load and display the preview specification.

[image]

Comment: Interesting.  But this seems odd to say the least.  Why would EnableSwaggerUi() even botherd with {apiVersion} as part of it's route template and then not even display the version as dictated by the url? Why should the user have to switch out the text box and then click explore? I see there is an option for EnableDiscoveryUrlSelector() -- this is also not desired.  Just want the Swagger UI to display the correct information based on the current route and it's values.